# Laravel 9 gives wrong validation error messages

Tags: laravel

I don't get the correct validation error messages, instead I get this dot-notation error message:

[image: wrong validation message]

When I submit the empty form, the `fabric` error message shows `validation.required` instead of `Fabric is required.`

Here is my code:

```php
$request->validate([
    'fabric'=>'required|in:3'
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted the old `resources/lang` folder and it worked.

Just remember to have the new `lang` folder, and its content, in your project root directory like this : https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/9.x/lang

Comment: great. it works like charm now. this changes is not mentioned anywhere in the release notes. on Laravel 8 vs Laravel 9 also not mentioned.

Comment: Glad it worked! And if it's not in the release notes, I'm sure the next person will also come here for an answer thanks to you! :)